# D3.js Sankey diagram: Add title (text) above each column of nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, sankey-diagram

I want to add titles above each column of nodes in a D3.js Sankey diagram. For example, I take this example: http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/5028304 and this is the result I want:

[Sankey graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYI2q.jpg)

I thought something like this but it doesn't convince me. I'm looking for other alternatives.

```js
        var columnNames=["step 1","step 2","step 3","step 4"];
        var distance=width/(columnNames.length-1);
        var pos=0;
        
        for (var i = 0; i < columnNames.length; i++){
            svg.append("text")
              .attr("x", pos)
              .text(columnNames[i]); 

            pos=pos+distance;
        }
```

How can I do that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it. I have updated the description with what I have tried.

Answer (score 0):

When the sankey is generated, each node in your sankey is assigned a dx value, which relates its position from the left. If you iterate through your nodes (graph.nodes), and create an array containing the unique dx values, you will know how many steps there are, and the x coordinate of the step label.

This array could be used as a data join to generate the labels, and the text could then be created using the value, eg label.text(function(d) { return "step " + d; })